# The method 'signInWithCredential' isn't defined

Tags: firebase-authentication, flutter

[dart] The method 'signInWithCredential' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseAuth'. [undefined_method]

my main.dart code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:aut'

final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  _MyHomePageState(){
    print("constrcer is called");

  }
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {

      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }


  Future<String> _testSignInWithGoogle() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
        await googleUser.authentication;
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    assert(user.email != null);
    assert(user.displayName != null);
    assert(!user.isAnonymous);
    assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

    return 'signInWithGoogle succeeded: $user';
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

My Pub file

```
name: myappname description: A new Flutter project.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# Read more about versioning at semver.org. version: 1.0.0+1

environment:   sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:   flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  banner: ^0.1.3   cloud_firestore: ^0.8.2     http: ^0.12.0   # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.   # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.   cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2   sqflite: any   firebase_auth: ^0.6.6   firebase_core: ^0.2.5+1   # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.   # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.


dev_dependencies:
     google_sign_in: ^3.0.4
     flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter. flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is   # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in   # the material Icons class.   uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:   # assets:   #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg   #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see   # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
# https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
# in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a   # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a   # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For   # example:   # fonts:   #   - family: Schyler   #     fonts:   #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf   #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf   #         style: italic   #   - family: Trajan Pro   #     fonts:   #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf   #  
- asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf   #         weight: 700   #   # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,   # see https://flutter.io/custom-fonts/#from-packages

> Blockquote
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter Phone authentication error original example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53730531/flutter-phone-authentication-error-original-example)

Answer (score 0):

try put the new version of the packages in your pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
    firebase_auth: ^0.6.2+1

firebase_database:
  firebase_core: ^0.2.5+1
```

Answer (score 0):

This samle is outdated. Just use code below

```
final FirebaseUser user =
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithGoogle(
  accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
  idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
);
```

instead of your code

```
final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
  accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
  idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
);
final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
```

Or use newer version of the package as @Marcos advised.